# Get combined array value from array with single value, that matches with another array with combined value

Tags: python, arrays, loops, logic

I have an array of single values with following format : 
`['apple', 'banana', 'potato', 'jelly', 'orange']`

And another array with following format : 
`['apple banana', 'jelly orange']`

And wants to output *only* when the first array sequence value matched with second array value :

> apple banana
> jelly orange

That mades following case didn't fullfill :
`['apple', 'banana', 'jelly', 'potato', 'orange']` 
 outputs only

> apple banana

I tried some implementation using python but still can't make this works as intended. 
What I've tried is to loop through the first array, and try match each value with the second array, but I can't seems to save the value outside the loop as intended output.
Any suggestion would be appreciated

EDIT :
I also need it to cover case when second array contains more than 2 string e.g second array => `["apple banana potato jelly"]` will still outputs
 "apple banana potato jelly"

Comment: So you want to print only items in the second array that are composed of adjacent elements from the first array?

Comment: @JohnGordon yes exactly. sorry for the complicated description

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
#Case
a=['apple', 'banana', 'jelly', 'potato', 'orange']
b=['apple banana', 'jelly orange']
    
c=[i+' '+i1 for i,i1 in zip(a,a[1:]) if i+' '+i1 in b ]

>>>['apple banana']

#Second case
a=['apple', 'banana', 'potato','jelly' , 'orange']
b=['apple banana', 'jelly orange']
    
c=[i+' '+i1 for i,i1 in zip(a,a[1:]) if i+' '+i1 in b ]

>>>['apple banana', 'jelly orange']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take pairs of values using `zip`. From this we just need to check if they are joined by a space in matches.

```
def fn(values, matches):
    matches = set(matches)
    rets = []
    for prev, curr in zip(values, values[1:]):
        value = prev + ' ' + curr
        if value in matches:
            rets.append(value)
    return rets

fn(['apple', 'banana', 'potato', 'jelly', 'orange'], ['apple banana', 'jelly orange'])
# ['apple banana', 'jelly orange']
fn(['apple', 'banana', 'jelly', 'potato', 'orange'], ['apple banana', 'jelly orange'])
# ['apple banana']
```